# kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused (flask, docker-compose)

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

i'm having problems with my flask app

having the premises:

Python, Flask, Celerey, MongoDB, RabbitMQ.

When I make a request to the API, I get the following return:

kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

and this only happens when I run docker-compose up, if I try to start the app from flask outside docker, everything works normally.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine AS builder

RUN pip install poetry

WORKDIR /backend

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root

FROM python:3.11-alpine

WORKDIR /backend

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

  celery_worker:
    build: .
    container_name: celery_worker
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:admin@rabbitmq:5672/
    restart: always
    command: celery --app src.task worker --loglevel=info 
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      
  flask_app:
    build: .
    container_name: flask_app
    command: python src/app.py
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - 5000:8080
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - celery_worker
volumes:
  mongodb_data:  # Volume para persistência dos dados do MongoDB
  rabbitmq_data: # Volume para persistência dos dados do RabbitMQ
```

src/app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from task import add

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    add.delay(1, 2)
    return "Docker compose working!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    port = os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '8001')
    print(f"Server listenning {host}:{port} !!!")
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=True)
```

src/task.py

```
import os 
from celery import Celery

broker = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'amqp://guest@localhost//')
celery = Celery('tasks')

@celery.task(queue='default')
def add(x, y):
    print(f'Adding {x} + {y}')
    return x + y
```

can anyone tell me how to solve this? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that celery is attempting to connect to the broker before it is available.

You might need to add a `healthcheck` to your `rabbitmq` service so that docker knows whether or not the container is "ready."

Otherwise, docker will assume the `rabbitmq` service is ready as soon as the container is created and its `CMD` process is started (even if that process has not gotten far enough along to actually bind to a port and start listening for connections).

e.g.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  ...

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3

  ...
```

I might have originally learned this from https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/docker-compose-healthcheck-for-rabbitmq